# Access Custom UITabBarController from custom UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have custom classes for my UITabBar and my UITabBarController. The custom UITabBar defines a button that when pressed should open the correct tab in the TabBar. However, I cannot seem to get the right code to open the tab.

How do I access my custom UITabBarController to change the tab, or otherwise can the current tab be change directly from the UITabBar?

```
class MainTabBar: UITabBar {

private var middleButton = UIButton()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupMiddleButton()
}

override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if self.isHidden {
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }

    let from = point
    let to = middleButton.center

    return sqrt((from.x - to.x) * (from.x - to.x) + (from.y - to.y) * (from.y - to.y)) <= 39 ? middleButton : super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}

func setupMiddleButton() {
    middleButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
    middleButton.backgroundColor = .white
    middleButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
    middleButton.layer.borderColor = self.tintColor.cgColor
    if let image = UIImage(named: "create") {
        middleButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
    middleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    middleButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    middleButton.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 0)
    middleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click), for: .touchUpInside)
    addSubview(middleButton)
}

@objc func click() {

   }
}
```

And the Controller:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delegate = self
    }
}

extension CustomTabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard let index = viewControllers?.index(of: viewController) else {
        return false
    }

    if index == 4 {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "What do you need?", message: "Please choose between Support and Training", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Support", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
            ChoiceStruct.choice = "support"
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 4
        }

        let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            // Do nothing
        }

        let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Training", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
            ChoiceStruct.choice = "training"
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 4
        }

        alert.addAction(action1)
        alert.addAction(action2)
        alert.addAction(action3)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }

    return true
}
}
```

The aim is to access tabBarController.selectedIndex from my MainTabBar class in order to change the selected tab

Comment: Since you have custom classes, its very difficult to answer without seeing your implementation. Please share your code to better describe your problem.

Comment: You need to override didSelectItem method in your custom tab bar and then show your required VC.

Comment: you need to provide some example code and make you question more clear by giving some example or images.

Comment: I've added my custom classes to the post @HAK

Comment: @VishalSonawane I cannot override this in the UITabBar, it does not show up in the list of items

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best solution was to move the code for the button to the UITabBarController rather than have a custom UITabBar class for just that purpose

Comment: How? UITabBarController has no override hittest